# При авторизации не запрашивает подтверждение кошелька ( MetaMask ) В чем может быть проблема?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, авторизация

Ситуация следующая: Разрабатываю приложение, в нем авторизация идет через Metamask, и решил я добавить WalletConnect для авторизации с телефона. Делал все по документации [WalletConnect](https://docs.walletconnect.com/)
Локально все отрабатывает как нужно, но когда я делаю деплой на сервер и запускаю проект уже на самом сервере, то я не могу получить подтверждение кошелька чтобы авторизоваться. Повторюсь, локально я получаю подтверждение когда сканирую QR code.
Вот как это должно работать:

- нажимаю на кнопку walletconnect, далее если мы с ПК то появляется QR code который мы сканируем телефоном и нас перебрасывает в приложение, где мы уже подтверждаем что хотим подключиться используя наш кошелек. Если мы с телефона, то мы просто нажимает иконку walletconnect где мы попадаем в список кошельков на выбор, где уже выбираем нужный нам и дальше по старой схеме с подтверждением кошелька. Проблема в том, что локально у меня работает подтверждение через QR code, а когда проект на сервере то нет. Как это решить? Для примера того как это должно работать - вот сайт, где все отрабатывает отлично [rarible](https://rarible.com/).
  Далее пример моего кода, может кто подскажет, в чем может быть проблема. Вот ошибка в консоле

  ```
   Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'importKey')
        at browserImportKey (browser.ts:44:1)
        at browserAesEncrypt (browser.ts:59:1)
        at Module.aesCbcEncrypt (aes.ts:8:1)
        at Module.encrypt (index.ts:49:1)
        at async WalletConnect._encrypt (index.ts:1172:1)
        at async WalletConnect._sendRequest (index.ts:790:1
  ```

)

```
    import React from "react";
    import WalletConnectProvider from "@walletconnect/web3-provider";
    import walletconnect from "../../../assets/icons/walletconnect.svg";
    import M from "materialize-css";
    import api from "../../../core/api/index";
    import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
    import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
    import { actions } from "../../../core/redux/actions";
    import classes from "./style.module.scss";

    //  Enable session (triggers QR Code modal)
    // ---------- APP -------------

    function AuthWalletConnect() {
      const history = useHistory();
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const provider = new WalletConnectProvider({
        infuraId: "807bed50f47c43a0b2c0c631c0ea7121",
      });
    
      const AuthUser = async () => {
        try {
          await provider.enable();
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      };
    
      provider.on("accountsChanged", (accounts) => {
        api.user.crateUser(accounts[0], accounts[0]);
    
        dispatch(actions.hash(accounts[0]));
    
        M.toast({ html: "auth succes" });
        history.push("/");
      });
    
      provider.on("disconnect", (code, reason) => {
        localStorage.clear();
        window.location.reload();
      });
    
      //  Enable session (triggers QR Code modal)
    
      return (
        <button className={classes.card} onClick={AuthUser}>
          <img src={walletconnect} className={classes.card__img} />
          <div className={classes.card__title}>Mobile Wallet</div>
        </button>
      );
    }
    
    export default AuthWalletConnect;
```